# How do I look through many images with a conditional element

Tags: python, sorting, image-processing

I have a folder that contains hundreds of images.

I am looking for a way to look through each image individually and decide whether to keep its name or move to the next.

Comment: You don't need any Python code to do that, just use a decent viewer like `feh`, then you can do `feh -f useful.txt *jpg` Either use left-mouse-click or right arrow to move through the images and press `delete` for ones you don't want. Press `q` at the end to exit and all the files whose names you didn't delete will be in file "`useful.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os and cv2 modules in python

```
import os
import cv2

path = 'path/to/folder/with 100 images'
arr = os.listdir(path)

for i in range(len(arr)):
    img = cv2.imread(path+arr[i])
    cv2.imshow(arr[i], img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if(k == 113):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This will open a window to view your image, all you have to do is press any key to move forward and load another image.

Press 'q' to exit.